# get the follow error info when "sudo apt install docker-compose"

Tags: docker-compose

> insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
>
> update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
>
> dpkg: error processing package lvm2 (--configure):  subprocess
>   installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
>
> Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.10) ...
>
> update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-105-generic Errors
>   were encountered while processing:  docker-ce  lvm2 E: Sub-process
>   /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

- docker version: `Docker version 18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40`
- system version: `Linux ci02-test 4.4.0-105-generic #128-Ubuntu SMP  x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Answer (score 0):

finally finished it by [install docker-compose from docker.com](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/#install-compose)